# How to show folders on Nautilus "Recent" list?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and on Nautilus (Files application on Ubuntu), there is a "Recent" function on the left sidebar that shows all the files that I recently opened using Nautilus.

[image]

However, it only shows files, but not folders. I would like to know if there is a way to make it show recently (or most frequently) accessed folders.

I know that I can add a column in Nautilus to make it show the folders where the files are located and that I can right-click the files and go to that location. But I think it would be much more intuitive and productive if the recent folders were shown directly.

Also (as a secondary question), I would love to be able to access recent folders when using the Save File Dialog inside applications... As shown below, the Recent option is not available.

[image]

This would save me a lot of time, because I often need to browse through folders multiple times when I am editing and saving a file located in a "far" location, say a folder in an external hard drive, for instance.

Is there a way to add this "Recent Folders" functionality to Nautilus?

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, I was wondering about where the recent files are stored. 
I found that nautilus (now called "Files", version 42.2 btw) stores them in an XML file `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`. And, for me, there are recently used folders among the files, definitely. Please, have another try.